# meaning of 'retail vertical'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "retail vertical" mean in this context?:

> If the barcode is used in the **retail vertical** then the barcode will be
>   unique. Since all retail items need to be unique so the databases used
>   will never get "confused" as to which product is being sold, the
>   barcodes have to be unique. However, in closed systems where barcodes
>   are used for serial numbers, part numbers etc., there can be identical
>   numbers. These types of barcodes only have a use within the system in
>   which they were originally printed for. They have no value outside
>   that closed system. An example would be a circuit board with a serial
>   number barcode on ...

Comment: The entire excerpt is poor English. I'm not sure *These types of barcodes only have a use within the system in which they were originally printed **for*** is even grammatical - it's certainly stylistically appalling. But *retail vertical* is just how this inferior "technical author" refers to the ***vertical market retail sector***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retailing),

> **Retail** is the sale of something in general.
>   **Retail** is the sale of goods and services from individuals or businesses to the end-user. Retailers are part of an integrated system called the supply chain.

According to [Glencoe Secondary Marketing Essentials DECA Connection Glossary](http://www.glencoe.com/sec/busadmin/marketing/dp/ap_and_acc_mktg/gloss.shtml),

> **vertical retailer**: A company that designs, produces, and sells its own products, without using middlemen or wholesalers.

When the word **vertical** alone is used in business discussions, it usually refers to either [vertical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_integration) or [vertical market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_market). In this case, **retail vertical** would refer to the vertical of the retail sector (where the barcode will be unique).

Comment: The term "retail vertical" sounds like jargon to me. I would never use it in a regular conversation.

Comment: It is indeed (a jargon). The full word should be *vertical market*, or *vertical integration*, or *vertical industry*. I'm not sure whether the writer of that sentence is a native speaker or not. Anyway, I believe that I've even heard *Let's go vertical!* once too. :)

Comment: Since we are speaking of *the retail vertical*, I believe the quote refers to the vertical of the retail sector, not retailing within any industry sector.

Comment: @choster Now I'm confused, is *the vertical of the retail sector* and *the retailing within any vertical industry sector* the same thing or different things? --It looks quite the same to me, as in *a Thai badminton player* vs. *a badminton player from Thailand*.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether we infer from the passage that the author is referring to *the* retail *sector* or retail *industry* (for two alternative terms), i.e. the subset of the economy involved in retailing, or if the author presumes the existence of multiple retail verticals (e.g. apparel retail, office supply retail, entertainment retail). I think the former interpretation is the most likely, but the latter is possible. It would be the difference between a Thai badminton player and a badminton player *in* Thailand.

Comment: @choster Imho, I believe that the author use *vertical* (adj.) as a noun, not *vertical* (n.) as a noun, and the use of *retail vertical* would refer to the *vertical* collectively and specifically refer to retailing in that *vertical*. I'm not sure if I'm 100% correct. What do you think? --By the way, I don't think the quote in OP's question is a very good English; or maybe I must read it the wrong way.

Comment: @choster After wading through almost hundred web pages, I believe that your suggestion (the vertical of the retail sector) is correct. The most clear-cut usage I found was this blog post: http://blog.vdcresearch.com/autoid/2011/07/rfid-in-2011-the-vertical-market-story.html.

Comment: Ugh, jargon! All this talk of verticals has left me horizontal.